# Jquery, Convert Title to Slug

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have a PHP script that does the following: It takes a string, for example, "This is a Great Blog Post, #1!", and returns the following string, "this-is-a-great-blog-post-1".

I'm not exactly a Jquery expert, that's why I'm asking this question. Does someone know of a Jquery (or Javascript, for that matter) script that will do the same thing as my script? Thanks in advance.

Will

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theres a [plugin](http://www.thewebsitetailor.com/jquery-slug-plugin/) for that! :)

Answer (score 16):

Or you could write your own version in about 45 seconds:

```
var str = "This is a Great Blog Post, #1!";
str = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/g,"");
str = str.toLowerCase();
str = str.replace(/\s/g,'-');
document.write(str);

// outputs "this-is-a-great-blog-post-1"
```

Comment: I'm going to try this. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Awesome! And add a trim before replace. It will remove first and last space from string. ( str = str.trim(); before str = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/g,""); )

Comment: can you modify this regex? when the user enter a slug with "-", it replacing the "-" with "", i want to make it still there. Please help

Answer (score 2):

Try this one [slugit-jquery](https://github.com/diegok/slugit-jquery),
it has decent multilanguage support.